# ZipException at deploying Java web app in OpenShift

Tags: java, tomcat7, openshift, zip

I'm trying to deploy a simple Java web app at OpenShift, on a Tomcat7 server cartridge.

I sftp'ed it with FileZilla on the /app-root/runtime/dependencies/jbossews/webapps application path with the default name ROOT.war, and the copy process ends successfully.

Openshift automatically tries to deploy the war, but a ZipException occurs (then, and every time I restart it manually from the OpenShift online console for that application, even when the following message is shown: "Application xxxxxx has restarted").

Here is the exception, copied from my application's Openshift's logs:

> Mar 26, 2017 11:39:00 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig undeploy
>
> INFO: Undeploying context []
>
> Mar 26, 2017 11:39:01 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
>
> INFO: Deploying web application archive /var/lib/openshift/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/app-root/runtime/dependencies/jbossews/webapps/ROOT.war
>
> Mar 26, 2017 11:39:01 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig beforeStart
>
> SEVERE: Exception fixing docBase for context []
>
> java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
>
> at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
>
> at java.util.zip.ZipFile.
>
> at java.util.zip.ZipFile.
>
> at java.util.jar.JarFile.
>
> at java.util.jar.JarFile.
>
> at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.
>
> at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.getJarFile(URLJarFile.java:69)
>
> at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarFileFactory.get(JarFileFactory.java:99)
>
> at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.connect(JarURLConnection.java:122)
>
> at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.getJarFile(JarURLConnection.java:89)
>
> at org.apache.catalina.startup.ExpandWar.validate(ExpandWar.java:220)
>
> at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.fixDocBase(ContextConfig.java:732)
>
> at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.beforeStart(ContextConfig.java:850)
>
> at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:376)
>
> at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
>
> at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
>
> at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:402)
>
> at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
>
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
>
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
>
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:632)
>
> at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1083)
>
> at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1880)
>
> at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:473)
>
> at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
>
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>
> Mar 26, 2017 11:39:01 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext resourcesStart
>
> SEVERE: Error starting static Resources
>
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid or unreadable WAR file : error in opening zip file
>
> at org.apache.naming.resources.WARDirContext.setDocBase(WARDirContext.java:136)
>
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:5089)
>
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5269)
>
> at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
>
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
>
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:632)
>
> at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1083)
>
> at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1880)
>
> at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:473)
>
> at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
>
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>
> Mar 26, 2017 11:39:01 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase addChildInternal
>
> SEVERE: ContainerBase.addChild: start:
>
> org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
>
> at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
>
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
>
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
>
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:632)
>
> at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1083)
>
> at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1880)

Surfing the web, I've found similar issues, and checked their answers, but nothing seems to work:

- I've checked that the war file, when renamed to .zip, is properly opened by WinRar with no problems.
- I've checked the permissions of the war file in the server after being copied, and set them to 777. Restarted the server but the problem remains.
- I've copied another application's war there, and was automatically deployed by OpenShift's tomcat.
- I've sent my war file to a colleague, who could deploy it on a local Tomcat7 server with no problems.

Any idea? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe SELinux is enabled?

Comment: All of this was done on a Win7 system...

Comment: I mean on OpenShift, on Redhat linux. With SELinux enabled any wired things happens. For example it can check owner, group and permission of war file.

Comment: try to set only rw permissions for owner (chmod 600 ROOT.war)

Comment: It didn't work, but thanks anyway.